# Set media alias to other server

Tags: nginx, media

I have two servers. First is application server with django project. Second is file server. Those servers are in the same internal network. I upload file via application server and save it on the file server (other ip).

I want to serve media file with nginx and add media alias in app server nginx conf to file server.

How can I do that?

My example nginx config:

```
location /media {
    autoindex on;
    alias /usr/local/www/mercury/media/;
}
```

Comment: It should work, paste whole config